# Has anyone on stackoverflow successfully used CouchDB for a webapp and deployed to a production environment?

Tags: couchdb

Has anyone on stackoverflow successfully used CouchDB and couchapp and deployed to a production environment? What type of QPS are you seeing when your web-app gets a lot of traffic? Have you had to use additional CouchDB instances to scale for traffic and throughput?  Have you used CouchDB on an Amazon EC2 instance? What are the things to watch out for, when using CouchDB for a web-application / mobile application backend?

Comment: Is this about CouchDB & couchapp or just CouchDB? It's hard to tell. There really isn't an easily identifiable programming question here? Each deployment of a CouchDB app is going to have it's own set of challenges based on the data, queries, updates, hardware, etc.

Comment: http://wiki.apache.org/couchdb/CouchDB_in_the_wild